# Is there an English word for "covering class" in the context of pre-measure?

Tags: measure-theory, terminology

Is there an english word for "covering class" in the context of pre-measure?

The word in Finnish appears as "peiteluokka", literally "covering class". But I've been unable to find an equivalent term in the context of *pre-measure*.

When I read about pre-measure in English, it appears that they only say "a collection of subsets".

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Premeasure.html

---

Let $K$ be collection of subsets of $X$, $K \subset 2^{X}$. $K$ is said to be a "covering class" in $X$, if $\emptyset \in K$ and if $X$ can be covered with countable many $E_j \in K$, i.e. exists sets $E_j \in K$ s.t.

$$X = \bigcup_{i=1}^{\infty}E_j$$

Comment: What's the exact definition?

Comment: @NateEldredge Added.

Comment: Terminology is fluid, but one name that is used is *set cover*, at least in combinatorics.

Answer (score 1):

In the textbook *Analysis III* of Herbert Amann and Joachim Escher appear the same concept named as **conforming cover**.

I dont know if this term is common in english textbooks (the book previously mentioned was originally written in german and after translated to english).